# Is it bad if a cable is higher current rating than a charger? Can a 6A cable charge at lower ampere?

Tags: charging, hardware

My phone adapter supports 11V=5A and 20V=3.3A

Can I use a 6A charging cable? Will it charge at 3.3A or 5A? I cannot find a good 3.3A or 5A cable.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things at play here.

1. The source (normally USBA) may supply a fixed voltage or may try to autosense to deliver the right voltage.
2. The cable, which may not connect to all the pins.  For example, it may not connect to both the voltage pins on the USBC.  Which is why some cables work better in one orientation, even though they are reversible.
3. The device, and what it is expecting, on what voltage and pin.

Normally it is best to use the cable that came with the device.  Otherwise look for a cable with a chip in the connector, this tries to solve the pin/voltage issue. Or look for a cable which says it will work at that voltage/power. Else, its trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a cable rated at higher amperage than the charger is safe and effective. The amp rating is (in simple terms) the maximum the cable can take without overheating. Higher-amperage cables are thicker, stiffer, heavier and more expensive, because they contain thicker wires with less electrical resistance.

The amperage that will be used in practice depends on what the phone and charger negotiate between themselves.